# API response fetching method not called CI

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have bad english, but i hope I can explain you my situation.
I have payment controller and two methods.

```
class payment extends MX_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model(get_class($this) . "_model", "model");
    }

    public function pay(){
        //Gets form data and sends to payment service
    }

    public function check(){
        //Gets response from payment service and acts according payment                         
        //status
    }
}
```

First sends data to payment service and second have to do something according payment response scenario.

So in my payment cpanel I wrote this url "htts://my-domain.do/payment/check" for response.
The first method works successfully, it sends all needed data, but my second "check()" method does not called.

When I simply write https://my-domain/payment/check it still not working, but when I call like this https://my-domain/index.php/payment/check it works.
My .htaccess also configured.

I use CI 3. Is there any one who had the problem like this.

My .htaccess file look like

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

And in app/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: put your code here.

Comment: Can you check once your config.php file with `$config['index_page']` parameter

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Sorry me that I asked without code. But now I edited my question, I will pleasent if you'll help me with advice why my url doesn't work

Comment: there are some cases depends on your hosting provider. Make sure `mod_rewrite` is `on` and `.htaccess` work well

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Thank you for your responses. My method works fine. But now I have other problem. My Payment Service gets 403 error when sends me payment object notification. So what I have to do next.
`[2019-02-27T12:10:26.622+03:00] INFO [] [HttpNotifier] [uid=0] server rejected http notification. id=46766420, uri=https://domaterial.ru/payment/result, attempt=2` 
This error message they send me.